# Could not find the project main file inside of the workspace config (src)

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular17

I started a personal project that using angular 17 in front-side and decided to use ngx-bootstrap. Ngx-bootstrap released a version(ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0) compatible with angular 17. But I got an error that says "Could not find the project main file inside of the workspace config (src)" when downloading ngx-bootstrap.

```
$ ng add ngx-bootstrap
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
    ✅️ Added "bootstrap
    ✅️ Added "ngx-bootstrap
Could not find the project main file inside of the workspace config (src)
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsWNe.png)

I tried to download again but got same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An issue has already been created on [`ngx-bootstrap` github page](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/6632) So you can just use [`ng-bootstrap`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) as per their suggestion which actually works great!

This is the [`code`](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/5c526057743588624fc27788082a4846fcebab03/src/schematics/src/utils/project-main-file.ts#L14) that breaks the command. It seems to expect app.module instead of main.ts

```
export function getProjectMainFile(project: workspaces.ProjectDefinition): string {
  const buildOptions = getProjectTargetOptions(project, 'build');
  if (!buildOptions.main) {
    throw new SchematicsException(`Could not find the project main file inside of the ` +
      `workspace config (${project.sourceRoot})`);
  }

  return buildOptions.main.toString();
}
```

If you really want ngx-bootstrap only, then you need to install it manually. Here is the  [installation guide](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation).

Comment: which means for now we don't have any solution for this problem, either downgrade to angular 16 or wait for ngx-bootstrap 12 to release.

Comment: @AmmarTheTrainer you can add ngz bootstrap manually instead of ng add

Comment: if you are talking about the solution give here
https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap
I was actually not able to get that, as I'm new to angular.

Comment: @AmmarTheTrainer in the last line of my answer, i have provided instruction to install manually!

Comment: the solution you mentioned is using Moduels, I'm working with standalone components. I don't have any modules in project. I'm using Angular17

Comment: @AmmarTheTrainer ok raise a question, if possible with a stackblitz I will check it

Answer (score 4):

this might be late , but for angular 17, there is a quick fix:
under angular.json , go to architect/build/options and add the property "main" and make it point to your main.ts , like this :

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "main": "src/main.ts", ...
```

you will get a warning saying that it is not allowed but just re run the ng add ngx-bootstrap and it will work just fine.

and before running ng serve , remove that property "main" so it can be built normally.

Comment: Just to mention this will work only for project with modules.